# Sybase INSERT INTO with Identity field?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have not seen this exact issue posted anywhere, and thus I'm starting to think it's just not possible, that I'm going about this the wrong way.

I'm trying to create a temp table with an auto-incrementing unique key using IDENTITY then using an INSERT INTO (fields...) SELECT @@identity, ... type statement, but I can't get it to work.

```
CREATE TABLE #someTemp (
    id INT IDENTITY UNIQUE,
    foo1 VARCHAR (20),
    foo2 VARCHAR (80),
    rand NUMERIC
)

INSERT INTO (id, foo1, foo2, rand)
SELECT id = @@identity, v.foo_bar, v.bar_foo, v.list
FROM #otherTemp a
INNER JOIN some_table v
    ON v.id = a.id
    AND v.suu = a.ooo
WHERE a.x = 'gotcha'
```

My code looks something more or less like this, however it gripes about illegal identity values, I have also tried using just `@@identity` without the `id =`, and a few other iterations.

Now I know that I can do something like this:

```
SELECT @@identity, blah, foo, bar
INTO #aTemp
FROM ...

INSERT INTO #someTemp (id, foo1, foo2, rand)
SELECT * FROM #aTemp
```

And this will work, but in my case I have anywhere from 1 to 5 iterations of this query executing with similar selects/froms and they all need to be joined together with a unique key for later calculations, and I don't know how many times it will be executed, so I would need to select each one into their own temp table, then insert them back into `#someTemp` later, and I would like to not go this route if there is a way to make this work.

If this already has an answer please link, or provide as much detail and examples as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you're inserting values for the column anyway, wouldn't it be both easier and more appropriate to make it *not* be an `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: In msSQL you need to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table] ON` in order to `INSERT` into an `IDENTITY` column. But as @JohnBollinger pointed out, your `id` column in `#someTemp` shouldn't be set to `IDENTITY`.

Comment: @@identity will return a single value; if your insert/select processes more than 1 row then @@identity will only give you one of the identity values

Comment: @daShier I had considered this, but I believe the `IDENTITY_INSERT` is for when you want to manually assign a value to the IDENTITY column that is auto incremented, and I because I don't know the order or number of times it will execute this wouldn't work, but I did try it yesterday.

Comment: I still don't understand why you are using the `IDENTITY` constraint for the `id` in the temp table in the first place.

Comment: I needed a unique auto-incremented field for each row inserted into this temp table, which could come from 1 or 5 different tables having anywhere from 0 to X records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just insert like this?

```
INSERT INTO (foo1, foo2, rand)
SELECT v.foo_bar, v.bar_foo, v.list
FROM #otherTemp a INNER JOIN
     some_table v
     ON v.id = a.id AND v.suu = a.ooo
WHERE a.x = 'gotcha';
```

Leave the `id` out.  It will be assigned automatically.

Comment: I have not tried that as of yet!  @Gordon you are a life saver!!  Thanks for the quick reply, exactly what I was looking for, can't say I'm a SQL or Sybase expert, just forced to work with it a lot and hadn't done this previously.

Comment: But you are not guaranteed that the `id` values will be the same for both tables with this method.

Comment: @daShier I guess my example wasn't the best then, I don't need the ID's to match up between the tables, I just need my new temp table to have a unique id for each row and this accomplishes that perfectly